# How to properly use std::align

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment

Is it correct that I consider [`std::align`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) as a runtime address calculation to meet the further logic of my program, i.e. if the program logic doesn't take into account any specific alignment, it doesn't make sense to use `std::align`?

Does using of `std::align` affect code generation? Is my understanding correct that, unlike `std::assume_aligned` from C++20, `std::align` is not a hint to a compiler?

Comment: How do you use `std::align` specifically? If you don't manage memory yourself, you don't need it.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you perhaps thinking of [alignas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::align` is an ordinary free function. It's not a compiler hint, no magic involved. It does affect code generation as any other function possibly affect code generation, i.e. it might be inlined, reordered etc., but not in any particular way.

As to what the function does and when it is used ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align)):

> Given a pointer ptr to a buffer of size space, returns a pointer aligned by the specified alignment for size number of bytes and decreases space argument by the number of bytes used for alignment. The first aligned address is returned.

So its is runtime construct that does some pointer arithmetic to return an address that is usable for a desired alignment. Imagine you want to store a `std::int64_t` at some memory address, but you don't know whether it's already correctly aligned (because it's in the middle of some buffer allocated with `std::malloc`), then `std::align` is your friend.

Here's the libstdcxx implementation:

```
inline void*
align(size_t __align, size_t __size, void*& __ptr, size_t& __space) noexcept
{
  if (__space < __size)
    return nullptr;
  const auto __intptr = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(__ptr);
  const auto __aligned = (__intptr - 1u + __align) & -__align;
  const auto __diff = __aligned - __intptr;
  if (__diff > (__space - __size))
    return nullptr;
  else
    {
      __space -= __diff;
      return __ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(__aligned);
    }
}
```

It is used e.g. in `std::monotonic_buffer_resource::do_allocate` - which is exactly the use case this function was made for.